# No data with DynamoDB query

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Unable to retrieve the record for the Nodejs query. The data (in JSON format) is given below along with the code. My data contains nested attributes which makes query queries difficult. Although the Nodejs query is valid, you can not have a data result.

## My JSON data structure under DynamoDB is:

```
[
  {
    "department": 1,
    "city": "city01",
    "info": {
      "markets": [
        { 
          "name": "marché de city01",
          "day": "vendredi matin",
          "location": "place de la république",
          "frequence": "hebdomadaire",
          "category": "tous produits",
          "merchants": "40",
          "link": "https://www.city01.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "department": 2,
    "city": "city02",
    "info": {
      "markets": [
        {
          "name": "marché de city02", 
          "day": "samedi matin",
          "location": "place de la liberté",
          "frequence": "hebdomadaire",
          "category": "tous produits", 
          "merchants": "80",
          "link": "https://www.city02.html"  
        },
        {
          "name": "marché de city02", 
          "day": "lundi après-midi",
          "location": "place de la mairie",
          "frequence": "bi-mensuel",
          "category": "tous produits", 
          "merchants": "60",
          "link": "https://www.city02.html"  
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

## My Nodejs code is:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "eu-west-1"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// recherche par contenu
console.log("Querying for markets of 1 (Ain) for city equal: city01");

var params = {
  TableName : "TestMarkets",
  ProjectionExpression:"#dep, #city, #info",
  KeyConditionExpression: "#dep = :dep and #city = :city",
  FilterExpression: "contains (#market, :ddd)",
  ExpressionAttributeNames:{
    "#dep": "department",
    "#info": "info",
    "#city": "city",
    "#market": "info.markets"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ":dep": 1,
    ":ddd": {
      "day": "vendredi matin"
    },
    ":city": "city01",
  }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  } else {
    console.log("Query succeeded.");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log("Dep: ", item.department + ", City: " + item.city);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(item.info));
    });
  }
});
```

Why The result gives no items? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: Not exception, but syntax error with N: 1.toString() ==> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the value of `ExpressionAttributeValues` in your query is invalid.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ":dep": {
    N: "1"
  },
  ":ddd": {
    M: {
     "day": {
       S: "vendredi matin"
     }
    }
  },
  ":city": {
    S: "city01"
  }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExpressionAttributeValues

Comment: OK, but with this section I have this error. 
`code`
    N: 1.toString()
             ^^
    
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: The problem is here? 

QueryFilter ==> FilterExpression in Nodejs
In a Query operation, QueryFilter is a condition that evaluates the query results after the items are read and returns only the desired values.

**This parameter does not support attributes of type List or Map.**

Comment: @COPINEPatrick ok yeah i typed this out without testing it, i put `1.toString()` because all values have to be strings, it would work if 1 was a variable instead, I updated my answer. Anyway, pay closer attention to the schema for what is expected in the docs.